# Graphs are no longer displayed in the output of Jupyter Notebook cells (on Visual Studio Code). How to solve this problem?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Since yesterday no more graph appears in the cell output when I run my Python codes written as Jupyter notebook on Visual Studio Code. Instead, only one line of text is displayed. For example :
<IPython.core.display.Javascript object>.

I think I changed something without realizing it in the settings of Visual Studio Code. However, I couldn't find anywhere how to solve this problem.

I restarted Visual Basic and my computer several times and used different kernels, but nothing changed.

I tried to solve the problem by clicking on "change presentation" left to the cell output and then to elect "image/png" as "mimetype", but I can't select "image" as it is not in the list of "mimetype".
[Example of a cell output where the graph is no longer displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDQCx.png)

The code was working before this issue.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the "%matplotlib notebook" statement at the beginning of my code.

After doing some investigation, it occurred to me that the "%matplotlib notebook" statement is not supported by Visual Studio Code.
This statement is used in jupyter notebooks to enable interactive graphics features such as the ability to move a 3D graphic in space with the mouse.

To solve this problem, just use "%matplotlib widget" instead of "%matplotlib notebook" on Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's something wrong with your ipython.

You can try to reinstall ipython by the following command in terminal:

```
pip uninstall ipython
pip install ipython
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your reply.
Unfortunately, I've just tried it and it didn't work. I'll try to solve the problem with my professor tomorrow.